# URL route from Laravel to Vue Router (page not found..)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and vue-js 2.4

**Laravel routes**

```
Route::get('/{component?}', 'HomeController@index');
```

**HomeController**

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
```

**Vue router**

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'myspaces', component: myspaces},
    { path: '/inspiration', component: inspiration },
];
```

When I click on this, about component is well displayed and the url is example.com/myspaces

```
<router-link to="/myspaces">myspaces</router-link>
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<div id="app">
        <v-app>

            <v-content>

                @Guest
                    <navigationloggedout></navigationloggedout>
                    <p>Not logged in</p>
                    <router-view></router-view>
                @else
                    <navigationloggedin></navigationloggedin>
                    <p>Logged in</p>
                    <router-view></router-view>
                @endGuest

            </v-content>

        </v-app>

</div>
```

**Issue**
When I enter example.com/myspaces directly. It doesn't actually load the page I want it to, it just loads the `welcome.blade.php` with the `<router-view></router-view>`. While I want it to load the specific component `myspaces`.

How can I find a way to directly reach my vue urls, like they are normal links? Vue normally works with example.com/#/myspaces. You can remove this with `mode: history`, however you can never actually go to links directly without a 404 error.

Comment: I advice you to installing Vue Devtools and check if Vue is loaded properly. Any console errors? Are Vue components located inside `resources/assets/js/views`? Is `app.js` included?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
Route::get('/{component?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('component', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

I've just replaced the **HomeController@index** with an anonymous function for simplicity sake.